# Report Pending Payments with mixed Monthly & Weekly intervals

Tags: sql

We are working with a database that tracks payment plans for patients.  Some patients pay monthly, some weekly, and some every other week.

The PaymentsSchedule table fields are Patient, Frequency, NextDueDate, PaymentsRemaining, Amount.  Once a payment is processed the NextDueDate and PaymentsRemaining fields are updated so that at any given time there is only one record representing all future payments for a given payment plan.

The report we want to generate would show all payments expected within the next month.  Something like this:

```
Report Date: 3/1/2014

Patient     Frequency      Next Date         Pmts Left     Amount
01          Monthly        3/01/2014         5             $100
02          Weekly         3/02/2014         3             $30
03          Weekly         3/02/2014         7             $25
04          Bi-Weekly      3/03/2014         4             $75
02          Weekly         3/09/2014         2             $30
03          Weekly         3/09/2014         6             $25
02          Weekly         3/16/2014         1             $30
03          Weekly         3/16/2014         5             $25
04          Bi-Weekly      3/17/2014         3             $75
03          Weekly         3/23/2014         4             $25
03          Weekly         3/30/2014         3             $25
```

I could set up 5 different queries for the 5 date possibilities (weekly) of a payment plan for the next 31 days, pull them together in a UNION and then filter out dates that are not in my time horizon but I would like to find a simpler solution.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Jim S

Comment: Some one is going to ask, so it might as well be me. What RDBMS and version are you using? It helps to tag as specifically as possible.

Comment: If the report date (day you run the query) were 3/10/14, would you want all payments through 3/31/14 (just through the current month), or through 4/10/14?

Comment: Database = Sequel Server 2008 R2

Comment: Yes, I would like a rolling date range, say 1 month, and/or allow the user to select a future stop date.